# How to verify Stokes theorem on a triangular pyramid?

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

I'm trying to solve a problem which is giving me some troubles, it's about applying Stokes' Theorem on the surface defined by:

$ x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 , (x + y + z) = 2 $

of the field

$ F = (x, -y, z) $

Whith the orientation n pointing towards the axis origin O.

The surface Σ should look like a triangular pyramid, with one of the vertices in the origin O. So I thought to just consider the pyramid face opposed to the vertex in O, so the one with the equation

$ (x + y + z) = 2 $

So i calculated

$ \int_{\delta (+) \sum }^{ } F * dr $

With Stokes' Theorem, considering

$ z = 2 - x - y $

and it returns

$ (\int_{0}^{2 - x}\int_{0}^{2} 2) = 4 $

So 4 or -4 depending on the orientation...

Then i'm requested to compute

$ \int_{\delta (+) \sum }^{ } F * dr $

with a direct method, using line integrals. Here comes my problem: how do I set the line integrals? Should I just consider

$ (x + y + z) = 2 $

or the other faces too?

I'm sorry for the bad English... thanks in advance!

Comment: Must you verify Stoke's theorem on ALL the surface of a pyramid? In that case it has no boundary, so you just need to show that all four surface integrals sum up to zero.

Comment: Yeah , i came to that conclusion initially, but given the orientation of the field, the problem actually requires the flux on the triangular face 
 $x + y + z = 2$

Comment: But then you must compute the line integral on the boundary of that face.

Comment: Yes basically, but i can't figure out why it gives me a wrong result, i'm parametrising this way:
__________________________________________
**y = 0**
$ x=t, z=2−t for t∈[0,2]
dr=(1,0,−1)dt
F=(0, -t, 2-t) $
__________________________________________
**z = 0**
$ x=2-t, y=t for t∈[0,2] 
dr=(-1,1,0)dt
F=(2-t, t, 0) $
__________________________________________
**x = 0**
$ z=t, y=2−t for t∈[0,2] 
dr=(0,-1,1)dt 
F=(2-t, 0, t) $
__________________________________________
But it returns 0, and I can't find what i'm missing out...
(Also, how the hell do you start a new line in this site? :S)

Comment: That's OK, because $\nabla \times \vec{F}=0$. I realize just now that you integrated $\vec{F}$, but you must integrate its curl instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a really dumb mistake in calculating the curl.
Just one more question if you don't mind... 
Considering the same problem, but with $ F = -y,x,-z $ instead, how would you calculate the flux with the Stokes' Theorem?
The **curl** would be $ (0,0,2) $ , **the normal** = $(1/ \sqrt{3}, 1/ \sqrt{3}, 1/ \sqrt{3} $ and the **dσ** = $  \sqrt{3} $ .
The product of these three values is 2.
Then I have to integrate 2: the borders of integration i'm thinking about are 0 < x < 2; 0 < y < 2-x.
Correct? :)

Comment: Yes, it's OK. Instead of calculating the integral you could just multiply the length of curl (2) by the area of the surface projection on the x-y plane (2). The result is 4.